# Angular environments local no file replacement

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile

I have configurations in angular.json for both development and production. What I want is for locally (ng serve) the file replacement doesn't happen. But when I docker build etc it does happen. Now I can make another environment but can't I just use environment.ts by default during ng serve?

**configurations**

```
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
```

```
            "development": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ],
```

So with development if I remove the file replacement it will use of course the environment.ts.

serve:

```
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
```

Now I could create another environment but doesn't make much sense (I know it is probably weird trying to avoid doing so) - would I just make one called local and make that the default configuration or what does everyone else do?

Summary:

- Two environments
- I want file replacement for my docker builds but not locally (so using environment.ts locally and development during builds)
- Avoiding creating another configuration

Comment: Just remove fileReplacements for development no?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have an apiUrl which is different between environment.ts and environment.dev.ts. I just want locally to run environment.ts (without file replacement) and then file replacement during my docker builds. Solve-able by creating another configuration (without filereplacement) but wanted to avoid doing so

Comment: But you don't have any configuration that uses environment.ts since both configurations use fileReplacements, why not copy the values in environment.dev.ts to environment.ts and remove fileReplacements for development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need another configuration called `local`.

Build:

```
            "local": {
              "fileReplacements": [
              ],
            }
```

Serve:

```
            "local": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:local"
            },
```

and then

`ng serve --configuration=local` or change  `"defaultConfiguration": "development"` to  `"defaultConfiguration": "local"` if it makes it easier for you